# Is it possible to calculate web site traffic size with Chromium browser?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to run a analyse for my website , calculate how much traffic it cost for each page , is that possible with Chromium Browser , maybe it's supported , but I didn't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to analyse performance problems for your website, then Speed Tracer would be the best chrome extension. [Speed Tracer in Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

> Speed Tracer is a tool to help you identify and fix performance problems in your web applications. It visualizes metrics that are taken from low level instrumentation points inside of the browser and analyzes them as your application runs. Speed Tracer is available as a Chrome extension and works on all platforms where extensions are currently supported (Windows and Linux).
>
> Using Speed Tracer you are able to get a better picture of where time is being spent in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work it out via the developer tools, but I'm not convinced it's the best way of getting that data.

It's there, but personally I'd recommend something like;

http://piwik.org/

From their blurb:

> "Piwik is a downloadable, Free/Libre (GPLv3 licensed) real time web analytics software >program. It provides you with detailed reports on your website visitors: the search >engines and keywords they used, the language they speak, your popular pages… and so much >more."

Which is set up on the server and should give you a much better view of the type of data you're looking for.

Hope that helps.